# Multiple associations with same table in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relational-database, backend

I'm making an application in Rails 5 that has models for Group and Person. A person can be a member of many groups, and a group can have many members. I know how to create that relationship. However, a person can also be a leader of many groups, and a group can have many leaders. Does Rails provide an easy way to model this?

Normally, I would create a table with foreign keys to represent each relationship, but I'm wondering whether Rails provides an easier way to set it up.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you have a join table named groups_persons, you just need to add there a new column,

```
add_column :groups_persons, :leader, :boolean
```

Comment: According to the [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-and-belongs-to-many-association-reference): "The use of extra attributes on the join table in a has_and_belongs_to_many association is deprecated."

Comment: That's a great idea, though that would mean that all leaders lookup would now have to perform checks against all member tuples as well. Is there a way to declare two join tables with different names? Like groups_members and groups_leaders

Comment: no, 1 relation - 1 table (in most cases). i think 1 join table should be enough